NextJS modules loading on every incoming request
I'm trying to use Map objects in an NextJS app as a kind of caching layer. The problem is that when running the app in dev mode (npm run dev), every incoming HTTP request causes the modules to load again, which resets the cache.
Example:

Middleware file is setup to invoke the "redirectToCognito" function, which is defined in the "redirectToCognito.ts" module/file.

This module has the following code in it:


import ExpiryMap from 'expiry-map';

console.log('***Stupid module is loading again!****');
const stateMap = new ExpiryMap(180000, []);

export default async function RedirectToCognitoAuthorization(subdomain: string) {

const state = '12345';
stateMap.set(state, 'abcde');
console.log(stateMap.size);

}
return;


Every time an HTTP request comes in, I see the console.log('Stupid module is loading again!*') message being printed.

This problem doesn't happen if I deploy to prod, so my first thought was that it could be related to Strict Mode. However, it seems to be disabled by default in the Mantine template that I'm using... From my "next.config.mjs" file:
export default withBundleAnalyzer({
  **reactStrictMode: false,**
  eslint: {
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
  experimental: {
    optimizePackageImports: ['@mantine/core', '@mantine/hooks'],
  },
});

This is very annoying... I have another module that loads records from a DB when the app starts. Every time a new request comes in, it loads all records again!
Any ideas on why this is happening?

Since this is a dev only issue I think the culprit may be the NextJS Fast Refresh functionality. To get around this I think the simplest way will be to just change how we are handling this if in dev.
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
 if (!global.stateMap) {
  console.log('Initializing stateMap');
  global.stateMap = new ExpiryMap(180000, []);
 }
  stateMap = global.stateMap;
} else {
 stateMap = new ExpiryMap(180000, []);
}

The above could help so to prevent reinitializing a new map every time and checking for an existing one we've previously stored. Not completely sure this will work but I do think the Fast Refresh is what is causing you issues here!

Thanks for the response. Typescript is having a hard time with the syntax above, but I will keep trying.

I'm getting closer to the root cause of the problem. I found that the problem only happens with dynamic paths such as "app/[id]/page.tsx" or "app/api/[tenant]/route.ts". So I think this problem has to do with some kind of caching mechanism on NextJS.

I believe NextJS HMR(Fast Refresh) is quite infamous for causing issues like this so looking those up might help you narrow down a solution too :)

I couldn't find anything on Fast Refresh that would explain this behavior. The documentation talks about it being relevant when making changes (edits) to the code. In my case, I'm not making any code changes at all... Not saying that Fast Refresh is not the problem. I just haven't been able to figure out how it would apply to my case yet. I will keep looking. Now that I have really narrowed down the problem to dynamic routes, I think I will re-post my question with an extremely simple test app that I created.
